# How to make an interface similar to multi-site for switching between multiple (single) sites for administrators?

Tags: plugins, multisite, plugin-recommendation, dashboard

I have a few WordPress sites and I want to make it easier to manage. I was thinking of being able to switch sites in the dashboard like WordPress multi-site, but when I was looking into it I see that's only for blogs inside blogs (if that makes sense). Is there anyway to link to different blogs together (I have around 5 blogs all with content on them so I don't want to make them in to 1 site with mapped domains).

So to sum up, I want to make it really easy/fast to switch between sites for the admins. I like how WordPress multi-site does it, but I don't want to move all the blogs in to one and map the domains, the domains are all on 1 server. Is this at all possable and if so how? Are there any plugins?

EDIT: If there is no way, how would I make 6 single WordPress sites into a WordPress multi-site?

Comment: @Jason Arr, Sorry.. never knew, i will keep the question on here for  a while just in case..

Comment: I've flagged it to have a moderator migrate the question to the WP site ...

Comment: Perchance, can you explain why you are reluctant to use Multisite, with domain mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an external services that let you manage multiple sites from one dashboard like [**manageWP**](http://managewp.com/).

But i would recommend moving them all in to a multisite install and here is a nice codex entry that shows just how to do that [**Migrating Multiple Blogs into WordPress Multisite**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Migrating_Multiple_Blogs_into_WordPress_3.0_Multisite)

Comment: I agree. Multisite, with domain mapping, is the way to go here.

Comment: ok, thanks.. looks like i will be making a multisite.. just wondering doing it this way will it improve performance at all or is it just the same?

Comment: One thing is for sure, you will be able to jump form one site's dashboard to another very easly :)